# Removing rows in R using if statement

Tags: r

I have a df with a column "SOS" that has a number value in each column except some of the columns have "Strength of Schedule" instead of a number value. How do i delete the rows that have this issue using an if statement so i dont need to manually go in and check row numbers?

Thanks

Comment: "a column [with] a number value in each column except some of the columns have "'Strength of Schedule'"—do you mean some of the rows have "Strength of Schedule?" Also, could you please add sample data with dput or the like?

Comment: If you don't mind not using an if statement try:
```df = data.frame(sos = c(0,1,2,3, "Strength of Schedule"))

  
df2 = data.frame(df[!(df$sos=="Strength of Schedule"),])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(sos = c(0,1,2,3, "Strength of Schedule"))

clean_df <- df %>%
  filter(sos != "Strength of Schedule")
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have your data frame in the variable `myDf`. You could try `myDf <- myDf[myDf$SOS != "Strength of Schedule", ]`. That gives you every element of the data frame where the value of the SOS column is not "Strength of Schedule".

Answer (score 0):

you can use a regex to filter out everything that is not only digits to make a more broad case if you need to.

```
df %>%
  filter(!str_detect(SOS, "Strength of Schedule"))

#positive or negative numbers.

df %>%
  filter(str_detect(SOS, '(^\\d+$)|(^\\d+\\.\\d+$)|(^-\\d+$)|(^-\\d+\\.\\d+$)'))
```